# Why is there crawl space water in a small channel and what is the best way to fix this?

Tags: water, crawlspace

What is the best way to go about fixing this water in the crawlspace? If water is coming in through the side is that normal? Or is there possibly a crack in the concrete wall and is allowing water through? For reference this is in CA after the giant rainstorm we just had that dumped 10+ inches of rain (which is abnormal)

[image: To the left side]

[image: To the right side]

[image: Center area]

Comment: I've had some luck with downspout extensions before, though they weren't enough to save us in San Jose this last weekend.

Comment: Why is there a channel there at all?  Where does the water go from the channel?  Was it intended to collect and carry water?  Where is the water coming from?  (You can't ask us that, you have to look and tell us).  Is the crawl space meant to be bone dry?

Comment: Looks to me like the channel was cut into the crawlspace floor after the fact, then new footings were poured. That's _my_ theory and I'm sticking with it! I do have to ask, why is there no cover on the electrical box in pic #2? Those need to be covered. Of course, if it's still work in progress, one will assume it will be covered before the work is completed...

Comment: Also, since this seems to be after an abnormally heavy rainstorm, it's not too surprising that there's a bit of moisture in the crawlspace. Everything else around you is probably flooded, so you shouldn't be shocked that your crawlspace is a bit wet, too. It shouldn't be _normal_, but this is an abnormal situation. Give it a few days for the area to dry out, then go see if your crawlspace is still wet. Check with several of the neighbors to see if theirs are still wet, too.

Comment: At least the connections are inside a box.  I've seen crawlspaces when the wire nut connections were just dangling in the air.

Comment: Looks like a dirt floor.  Is that correct?  If so, and if you're in a relatively dry part of CA, the water will just seep into the soil (which is probably bone dry most of the time.  If that's all the water you got in your crawlspace after 10" of rain, consider yourself lucky!

Comment: No idea why there is a channel there at all. Crawl space was pretty dry before this giant rainstorm. Not sure why there is no cover on the electrical box. Will fix it.

Comment: The floor is really hard. I'd say it is some bumpy concrete or something. There are rocks embedded in it.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to speculate on where the water is coming from, with 10+ inches of rain.  It could have come in through one of your crawl space vents (I've experienced that first hand).  Or just seeped up around the bottom of the foundation/footer because of hydraulic pressure from water in the outside soil.  Or it could be coming in through some hairline cracks in your foundation.